# Is there any way to retrieve the Case Labels of a Switch Statement as a Collection in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, switch-statement

I have written a parser for a typical format (proprietary) of text in a text file. One of the primary tasks of the parser is to convert function name in the call, secondary being to mutate the parameters and/or their position in the call.

Example:

```
Func1(bla1,bla2,bla3)
```

becomes

```
Func2(bla1) // again, licensing issues, so cannot show the actual file
```

There's a minimum of 50 separate such functions. The program is working fine. The only problem is that if some new functions are added in the future, I will have to alter 2 things, an ArrayList which holds the name of all the functions whose calls need to be modified, and a switch statement which actually modifies the calls. It might happen so that, a particular function name is present as a case in the switch statement, but me being the forgetful freak that I am, the function name is not present in the ArrayList.
What I was thinking was that if I could instead ask Java to generate that ArrayList for me (its just a List of strings, with each entry being a case label), it might help.
Is there any way in Java 8 to do this?

Example:

```java
String functionName = "";
switch(functionName) {
case "Func1":
    break;
case "Func2":
    break;
//bla bla bla
default:
    //whatever
} 

List<String> functionNames = <some code which returns a Collection of all case names>;
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, can you please rephrase the question also provide a better code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think you can use java enums to compare case labels and also you can get all enum values dynamially

Comment: It's not clear what your `switch` statement is actually doing or should do, because you have left it out. Could you add more details?

Comment: This is totally an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Looks like you should use a `Map` to store these strings, plus perhaps also polymorphism, instead of trying to get the case labels of a switch statement.

Comment: I am really sorry. I really can't be think of a better way to put if :(

Comment: In addition to Sweeper’s alternative, you could use an `enum`. Then, you can’t add a `case` to the `switch` without adding the constant to the `enum` type, which will be reflected by the `enum` types `values()` return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From the Java Language specification** :  `14.11. The switch Statement` [click the link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#:~:text=of%20throw%20statements.-,14.11.%C2%A0The%20switch%20Statement,-The%20switch%20statement)  , you can see that cases of the Switch can be a **ConstantExpression** or an **EnumConstantName** and following the definition of the ConstantExpression here [click the link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#:~:text=A%20compile%2Dtime%20constant%20expression%20is%20an%20expression%20denoting%20a%20value%20of%20primitive%20type%20or%20a%20String%20that%20does%20not%20complete%20abruptly%20and%20is%20composed%20using%20only%20the%20following%3A) .

So the values in each case statement must be compile-time constant values of the same data type as the switch value (**literals**, **enum constants**, or **final constant variables** : marked with the final modifier and initialized).

---

**You are looking for the answer of the question : can the number of cases be known At Runtime** ? **No it cannot because the cases must be a compile time constants .**

```
public class Swith {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        switch (lst.get(0)) {
        case lst.get(0): //Compilation error : case expressions must be constant expressions
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to list the `case` labels from a `switch`.

However, you could maintain a `Map` which maps function names to their corresponding actions-to-be-performed:

```java
Map<String, Runnable> functions = Map.of(
    "func1", () -> doSomething(),
    "func2", () -> doSomethingElse(),
    ...
);
```

To get the function names, you could just use `keySet()` to get all function names (or use `containsKey` to check whether a function name exists). And instead of the switch statement, you could just use

```java
functions.get(functionName).run();
```

---

<sup>Note that I used a `Runnable` as map value, which allows to perform some code, without input. That is because you have not shown what actions your switch cases are actually doing, or what *"mutate the parameters and/or their position in the call"* actually looks like. You may want to replace `Runnable` with something more appropriate.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically derive the collection of case statements from the switch.  However, you can create an enum of the functions and use that in the switch and to assemble your List.  For example...

```
public enum Function {
  FUNC1("func1"), FUNC2("func2"), ... ;
  private String functionName;
  private Function(String functionName) { ... }
  public String functionName() { ... }
  public static Function byFunctionName(String functionName) { ... }
}
```

Find the Function instance that matches the String you are currently switching on and switch on the Function.

```
Function function = Function.byFunctionName(functionName);
switch (function) {
  case FUNCT1: ...
  case FUNCT2: ...
  ... etc ...
}
```

And the List of function names can be created from the same enum.

```
List<String> functionNames = Arrays.stream(Function.values())
        .map(e -> e.functionName())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```